# Subdivision Surface Mesh Issue

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image]

Just making this anvil off a tutorial trying to get back into the motion after a long hiatus and I'm having a large issue with the *Subsurf* modifier.

My mesh is all looped very well and every face is a quad with motion going in every direction. I don't know if it is a bug or a setting problem. No matter how many loop cuts I add or how many I move it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: could you have double geometry? the imager is not enough to understand...